# scikit-learn: fit() can't enable sample_weight when pipeline is involved

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am using a Scikit-Learn code from others to build a prediction tool. The original code works just fine but I need to add `sample_weight` to the prediction tool.

Having searched for solutions in different documentation, I found that the major issue is that pipeline in Scikit-Learn does not support `sample_weight` very well.

```py
# creating pipeline
pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100))

hyperparameters = {'randomforestregressor__max_features': ['auto'],
                   'randomforestregressor__max_depth': [None]   }


clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, hyperparameters, cv=10, verbose=10)

clf.fit(X_train, Y_train
        #        , fit_params={'sample_weight': W_train}
        # , fit_params={'sample_weight':W_train}
        # , **{'randomforestregressor__sample_weight': W_train}
        )

# testing model
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
r2_score(Y_test, pred)
mean_squared_error(Y_test, pred)
print(r2_score(Y_test, pred))
print(mean_squared_error(Y_test, pred))


# 保存模型以便将来使用
joblib.dump(clf, 'rf_regressor.pkl')
```

I've tried to insert `sample_weight` in different locations, but it all shows failure. 
Can anyone help tell me where to insert the `sample_weight` with `pipeline` in place,
OR realize the steps (including `sample_weight`) without using `pipeline`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem has to be with `W_train` because find my example below with your code, which works pretty fine.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# creating pipeline
pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                         RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100))


from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
hyperparameters = {'randomforestregressor__max_features': ['auto'],
                   'randomforestregressor__max_depth': [None]   }


clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, hyperparameters, cv=10, verbose=10)

clf.fit(X , y,
        **{'randomforestregressor__sample_weight': np.random.choice([0,2,3,5],size=len(X))})

#
Fitting 10 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 10 fits
[CV] randomforestregressor__max_depth=None, randomforestregressor__max_features=auto 
[CV]  randomforestregressor__max_depth=None, randomforestregressor__max_features=auto, score=0.385, total=   0.2s
...
```